# react custom hls player

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello guys I am currently use hls.js in my react project . i have a issue with changing quality level , I created custom quality level changer button and when that button triggered video is restarted . I just want to know is there any way for hls js to change quality without restarting ?
this is part of Hlsplayer file

```
useEffect(() => {
        let hls: Hls;

        function _initPlayer() {
            if (hls != null) {
                hls.destroy();
            }
            const newHls = new Hls({
                enableWorker: false,
                ...hlsConfig,

            });
            if (playerRef.current != null) {
                newHls.attachMedia(playerRef.current);
            }

            newHls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, () => {
                newHls.loadSource(src);
            });

           



           

            newHls.once(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, (event, data) => {
                localStorage.setItem("player-config", JSON.stringify(data))
                setConfig(true)
                if (autoPlay) {
                    playerRef?.current
                        ?.play()
                        .catch((e) => {
                                console.log(e)

                            }
                        )
                } else {
                    // playerRef.current?.play()
                }
                // playerRef.current?.play()

            });

            newHls.on(Hls.Events.ERROR, function (event, data) {
                if (data.fatal) {
                    switch (data.type) {
                        case Hls.ErrorTypes.NETWORK_ERROR:
                            newHls.startLoad();
                            break;
                        case Hls.ErrorTypes.MEDIA_ERROR:
                            newHls.recoverMediaError();
                            break;
                        default:
                            _initPlayer();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

            hls = newHls;
        }

        // Check for Media Source support
        if (Hls.isSupported()) {
            _initPlayer();
        }
        if (playerRef?.current?.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
            playerRef.current.src = src
        }

        return () => {
            if (hls != null) {
                hls.destroy();
            }
      

        };
    }, [autoPlay, hlsConfig, playerRef, src, currentLevel]);
```

I just change quality with sending currentLevel Props to this component

```
    <ReactHlsPlayer
                    src={String(film.data.hlsLink)}
                    controls={false}
                    playerRef={playerRef}
                    width="100%"
                    autoPlay={false}
                    height="100%"
                    currentLevel={currentLevel}
                    setCurrentLevel={setCurrentLevel}
                    setConfig={setConfig}
                   
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create a handler that changes `currentLevel` of `Hls instance`.
I would recommend this option:

```
const handleQualityLevel = (levelId: number) => {
    hlsInstance.current.currentLevel = levelId; }
```

Here you have to provide `levelId` which you can get from levels array of `Hls instance`.

Also you need to control the state of currentLevel, I would suggest this event:

```
hlsInstance.current.on(Hls.Events.LEVEL_SWITCHING, (_, data) => {
    setCurrentQualityLevel(data.level);
```

And the last problem is to have above handler outside of `useEffect`. I resolved it in this way:

```
  const hlsInstance = useRef(new Hls());
```